# How to use OpenCV video capture with custom video input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, ros

I am trying to use the LK Optical Flow from [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html), to get some motion estimation into a robot simulation made with ROS+Gazebo.

I could manage to make properly the bridge between ROS and OpenCV via cv_bridge, as per the code below, and could implement some sample features which work "frame-by-frame" without major issues.

However, the optical flow tutorial reference seems to accept only video inputs, such as webcam and/or saved video files, and this is where I got stuck.

How could I apply the LK Optical flow in a "frame-by-frame" approach, or configure my cv_bridge to act as a "custom" camera device?

This is my cv_brige so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import roslib
import rospy
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError


class OpticalFlow(object):



    def __init__(self):

        #Setting up the bridge and the subscriber
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/realsense/color/image_raw", Image,self.image_callback)
        
        # Parameters for Good Features Detection
        self.feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                                qualityLevel = 0.3,
                                minDistance = 7,
                                blockSize = 7 )

        # Parameters for Lucas-Kanade optical flow
        self.lk_params = dict( winSize  = (150,150),
                                maxLevel = 2,
                                criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))

        # Create some random colors for the tracking points
        self.color = np.random.randint(0,255,(100,3))



    def image_callback(self,ros_image):

        # Using cv_bridge() to convert the ROS image to OpenCV format
        try:
            cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(ros_image, "bgr8")#bgr8
            hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(cv_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)
    

        cv2.imshow("Robot Image", cv_image) # The actual (non-processed image from the simulation/robot)
        #cv2.imshow('Image HSV', hsv_image)
        #cv2.imshow('Image Gray', gray)
        frame = np.array(cv_image, dtype=np.uint8)


        # Calling the Optical Flow Function
        display = self.optical_flow(frame,self.feature_params,self.lk_params,self.color)


    
    def optical_flow(self,frame,feature_params,lk_params,color):
        
        
        old_frame = frame
        old_gray = cv2.cvtColor(old_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        p0 = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(old_gray, mask = None, **feature_params)
        mask = np.zeros_like(old_frame)
        while(1):
            
            newframe = frame
            frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(newframe, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Calculating the optical flow
            p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)
            
            # Select good points
            good_new = p1[st==1]
            good_old = p0[st==1]

            # Draw the tracks
            for i,(new,old) in enumerate(zip(good_new, good_old)):
                a,b = new.ravel()
                c,d = old.ravel()
                mask = cv2.line(mask, (a,b),(c,d), color[i].tolist(), 2)
                frame = cv2.circle(frame,(a,b),5,color[i].tolist(),-1)
            img = cv2.add(frame,mask)
            
            cv2.imshow('LK_Flow',img)                    
            k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
            if k == 27:
                break

            # Now update the previous frame and previous points
            old_gray = frame_gray.copy()
            p0 = good_new.reshape(-1,1,2)
            


def main():

    optical_flow_object = OpticalFlow()
    rospy.init_node('KLT_Node', anonymous=True)
    rospy.loginfo("\nWaiting for image topics...\n...")
    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo("\nShutting Down...\n...")
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I also would like to know, if possible, where I can find more information about how to manipulate those parameters (from the tutorial):

```
# params for ShiTomasi corner detection
feature_params = dict( maxCorners = 100,
                       qualityLevel = 0.3,
                       minDistance = 7,
                       blockSize = 7 )
# Parameters for lucas kanade optical flow
lk_params = dict( winSize  = (15,15),
                  maxLevel = 2,
                  criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 10, 0.03))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_frame, cur_frame, ...)` or `cv2.calcOpticalFlowFarneback(old_frame, cur_frame, ...)` (dense optical flow). There is a bunch of information about these methods  on [the cv2 website.](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html) From personal experience, these methods work great!

Let me know if you have any questions or problems!

Comment: Thank you. So, in that case, Would I skip the video input and pull the frames from the callback function directly?

I'll try to realize how to do that.

Comment: No problem. Yup, I believe that would work. I think you would want to store the previous frame as an instance attribute so that it's accessible for calculating optical flow with the frame calling the callback.

Comment: I am having some issues now, 
I basically replaced the `cap.read()` by the frame inside the callback, and created one optical_flow() func as per the tutorial and calling it inside the callback function, 
But it is not actually calculating the flow... it just flash the optimal points as if it is starting a new estimation per frame.

Comment: Would you mind editing your original question with your new code please? It's a little hard to understand what code you have.

Comment: Updated with the new code, as requested. 
Thank you